# Flutter nested widgets setState does not work as intended

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate

I have the following structure:

- **MainBlock**. main statefull widget. contains two widgets **BlockA** and **BlockB**.
- **BlockA**. contains a text and a button.
- **BlockB**. contains another widget, **BlockBCard**, which will be used several times (two times in this example).

**What works as intended?** When I click on the button in **BlockA**, the content of the text field in **BlockA** and **BlockBCard** changers as desired.

**Now to my problem:**

In **BlockB**. In order to use `setState`, I changed **BlockB** to a **StatefulWidget**.
Clicking on the button in the **BlockBCard**, changes the text field in both **BlockBCard’s** as desired.
But the content of the text field in **BlockA** does not change.

**how can I implement the following:**
Click on the button in one of the **BlockBCard’s**, both the text field in **BlockA** and the two text fields in **BlockBCard** change?

Click on the button in one of the **BlockBCard’s**, the text field in **BlockA** changes and the text field in the **BlockBCard** changes but the text field in the second **BlockBCard** does not change.

[image]

Sample Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
int testCounter = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainBlock(),
    );
  }
}
// ------------------------------------ Stateless Widget <<<

class MainBlock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainBlockState createState() => _MainBlockState();
}

class _MainBlockState extends State<MainBlock> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        color: Color(0xFF122C39),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: BlockA(
                counter: testCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    testCounter++;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BlockB(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockA extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final Function button;

  BlockA({this.counter, this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF265672),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: button,
              child: Text(
                'Button',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BlockBState createState() => _BlockBState();
}

class _BlockBState extends State<BlockB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF265672),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: BlockBCard(
              counter: testCounter,
              button: () {
                setState(() {
                  testCounter++;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: BlockBCard(
              counter: testCounter,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockBCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final Function button;

  BlockBCard({this.counter, this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      color: Color(0xFF4C93C7),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: button,
              child: Text(
                'Button',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OK, I have now improved my code so that the button in the **BlockBCard's** calls a function **myBrain** that executes a calculation, the result of which is output in **BlockA**.

Now I would like to increase the text field in the **BlockBCard's** by 1, **but only in the respective card in which the button is pressed** and not in all cards. With my current code, all cards are incorrectly increased by 1.

In this example there are only two cards, but in the implementation there will be multiple cards.

**Here is my current code.** to simplify the example, I removed **BlockB** and placed the **BlockBCard's** directly into the MainBlock:

**How can I increase the text field in the BlockBCard's by 1, but only in the respective card in which the button is pressed and not in all cards?**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainBlock(),
    );
  }
}

// OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MainBlock >>>
class MainBlock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainBlockState createState() => _MainBlockState();
}

class _MainBlockState extends State<MainBlock> {
  int totalCounter = 0;
  int singleCounter = 0;

  void myBrain() {
    totalCounter = totalCounter + 5;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        color: Color(0xFF122C39),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: BlockA(
                counter: totalCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    totalCounter = 0;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BlockBCard(
                counter: singleCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    myBrain();
                    singleCounter++;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BlockBCard(
                counter: singleCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    myBrain();
                    singleCounter++;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
// OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MainBlock <<<

// OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO BlockA >>>
class BlockA extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final Function button;

  BlockA({this.counter, this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF265672),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: button,
              child: Text(
                'Button',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO BlockA <<<
// OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO BlockBCard >>>

class BlockBCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final Function button;

  BlockBCard({this.counter, this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      color: Color(0xFF4C93C7),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: button,
              child: Text(
                'Button',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
// OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO BlockBCard <<<
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the issue because when you change the value of blockB it could not rebuild ta blockA but it change the global value if you will want to change the blockA's from blockB you should pass as like blockA.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
int testCounter = 0;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainBlock(),
    );
  }
}
// ------------------------------------ Stateless Widget <<<

class MainBlock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainBlockState createState() => _MainBlockState();
}

class _MainBlockState extends State<MainBlock> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        color: Color(0xFF122C39),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: BlockA(
                counter: testCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    testCounter++;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BlockB(
                  counter: testCounter,
                  button: () {
                    setState(() {
                      testCounter++;
                    });
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockA extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final Function button;

  BlockA({this.counter, this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF265672),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: button,
              child: Text(
                'Button',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockB extends StatefulWidget {
  final int counter;
  final Function button;

  BlockB({this.counter, this.button});

  @override
  _BlockBState createState() => _BlockBState();
}

class _BlockBState extends State<BlockB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF265672),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: BlockBCard(
              counter: testCounter,
              button:widget.button,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: BlockBCard(
              counter: testCounter,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockBCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final Function button;

  BlockBCard({this.counter, this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      color: Color(0xFF4C93C7),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: button,
              child: Text(
                'Button',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahah hello again ;) We mostly did the same thing however I would argue that using a mutable global variable is really the mistake being made here. Sure you need to pass it down but if you understand that you should never create a mutable global variable you are forced to pass it down anyway

Comment: @Lulupointu yap understand mutable global variable is really the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jahidul Islam explained, you have to pass your data from `MainBlock` to `BlocB` as you do from `MainBlock` to `BlocA`.

In general in Flutter, you want to avoid using mutable global variable precisely for that reason. When a variable update, flutter does **not** know about it. If you call `setState` the widget tree **bellow** will be rebuild.
This is why you will often hear "Lift the state up" because the state has to be contained in a high enough widget so that it can be passed down *through the widget tree* to every widget that needs it. In your case, since `BlocA` **and** `BlockBCard` need the `counter`, it has to be created inside there lower common ancestor: `MainBlock`.

Here is the concrete implementation but the most important thing is to have understood the reasoning explained above:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainBlock(),
    );
  }
}

class MainBlock extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainBlockState createState() => _MainBlockState();
}

class _MainBlockState extends State<MainBlock> {
  int testCounter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        color: Color(0xFF122C39),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: BlockA(
                counter: testCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    testCounter++;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BlockB(
                counter: testCounter,
                button: () {
                  setState(() {
                    testCounter++;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockA extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final VoidCallback button;

  BlockA({required this.counter, required this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF265672),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: button,
              child: Text(
                'Button',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockB extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final VoidCallback button;

  BlockB({required this.counter, required this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF265672),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: BlockBCard(
              counter: counter,
              button: button,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: BlockBCard(
              counter: counter,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlockBCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final int counter;
  final VoidCallback? button;

  BlockBCard({required this.counter, this.button});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      color: Color(0xFF4C93C7),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: button ?? (() {}),
              child: Text(
                'Button',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see the logic here by passing the state state through the widget tree. why to avoid using mutable global variables is yet not clear at my level of coding.

Comment: Well you saw for yourself what kind of bad behavior global variables yield didn't you?

Comment: yes it is much clearer now and I improved my code and understand the relationship. but it is still not clear how to increase the text field by 1 only in the respective card in which the button is pressed and not in all other cards.

Answer (score 0):

If we refresh the `MainBlock` it's children will also get the updated state. We can  use callback for it.

On `BlocKB`

```dart
class BlockB extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback ontap;
  const BlockB({
    Key? key,
    required this.ontap,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _BlockBState createState() => _BlockBState();
}

class _BlockBState extends State<BlockB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      color: Color(0xFF265672),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: BlockBCard(
              counter: testCounter,
              button: () {
                // setState(() { /// we dont need it while parent widget will refress it
                testCounter++;
                // });

                widget.ontap();
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: BlockBCard(
              counter: testCounter,
              button: () {
                /// you may also wanted to increment here

                testCounter++;

                widget.ontap();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**On MainBlock**

```dart
       Expanded(
              child: BlockB(
                ontap: () {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ),
```